# Application of Bayes-theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

In order to apply the **Bayes-theorem** to a real world example, I have been given this problem :

> *A barometer is used to forecast the weather. However the prediction may be erroneous. It is observed that in $20$ cases over $200$ rainy
>   days the barometer has predicted good weather, and in $20$ cases over
>   $100$ good days it has predicted rain. The local tourist guide says
>   that $10\%$ of the days in a year are rainy. What is the probability
>   that it will rain if the barometer predicts rain ?*

Answer $\approx 0.333 $

**My attempt** : Let $R$ be the event "*it rains*" and $B$ the event "*the barometer predicts rain*". I am asked to compute $P(R|B)$. By the bayes-theorem, I know that $$P(R|B) = \frac{P(B|R)P(R)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|R)P(R)}{P(B\cap R) + P(B\cap \bar{R})} = \frac{P(B|R)P(R)}{P(B|R)P(R) + P(B|\bar{R})P(\bar{R})}$$
If I am not mistaken, I am given that $P(R) \approx 1/10$, $P(R \cap \bar{B}) \approx \frac{20}{200} = 1/10$ and $P(\bar{R} \cap B) \approx \frac{20}{100} =1/5$.

**My question** : How can I calculate the remaining unknown $P(B|R)$ (or $P(B \cap R)$)?

Comment: Hint: it's given in the text. $\mathrm{P}(B | R)$ is the probability that the barometer predicts rain on a rainy day, which would be the given fraction of rainy days where the barometer actually predicts rain.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that :d Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but not quite correct.  It is not true that $\Pr[R \cap \bar B] = 1/10$ and $\Pr[\bar R \cap B] = 1/5$.  These are probabilities of the joint event occurring.  What you were instead supplied are conditional probabilities:  for example, in the first case, when the weather actually did rain $200$ times, the barometer was in error $20$ of these times.  When it actually did not rain $100$ times, the barometer was in error $20$ times.  This would suggest that $$\Pr[\bar B \mid R] = \frac{20}{200} = \frac{1}{10}, \\ \Pr[B \mid \bar R] = \frac{20}{100} = \frac{1}{5},$$ respectively.  Then to recover the respective joint probabilities, you must multiply by the probability of the given event (i.e. $\Pr[R]$ the unconditional probability of rain, and $\Pr[\bar R]$, the unconditional probability of no rain).  This is because it is much more likely that there is no rain; thus the respective probability of an erroneous prediction in the case of no rain is given greater weight than the probability of an erroneous prediction in the case of rain.

Comment: How can I convince myself that the problem does not give me the joint probability? I feel like the problem is ambiguous in the sense I could choose either to interpret it by  "It will rain if the barometer predicts rain in 90% of the cases" and "It will rain and the barometer predicts rain in 90% of the cases" depending on weither you measured it before it happens or not.

Comment: You know that it must be a conditional probability that is being described, because you are told that in the $200$ times that it rains, the barometer is wrong $20$ times.  In other words, **given** that it rained, the barometer was wrong $10\%$ of the time.  It does not mean that the probability of it raining *and* the barometer being wrong is $1/10$, since it only rains on average once out of $10$ days.

Comment: Another way to understand that it must be conditional is to observe that the probability of rain on any given day is $\Pr[R] = 0.10$.  Therefore, it is nonsensical to say that $\Pr[B \cap R] = 0.90$.  The chance $B$ and $R$ occurring simultaneously cannot be greater than the probability of $R$ occurring irrespective of event $B$.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks :)